# Python3: Converting or 'Casting' byte array string from string to bytes array

Tags: python-3.x, casting, arrays

New to this python thing.
A little while ago I saved off output from an external device that was connected to a serial port as I would not be able to keep that device. I read in the data at the serial port as bytes with the intention of creating an emulator for that device.
The data was saved one 'byte' per line to a file as example extract below.

```
b'\x9a'
b'X'
b'}'
b'}'
b'x'
b'\x8c'
```

I would like to read in each line from the data capture and append what would have been the original byte to a byte array.
I have tried various append() and concatenation operations (+=) on a bytearray but the above lines are python string objects and these operations fail.

Is there an easy way (a built-in way?) to add each of the original byte values of these lines to a byte array?

Thanks.

M

Update
I came across the .encode() string method and have created a crude function to meet my needs.

```
def string2byte(str):
    # the 'byte' string will consist of 5, 6 or 8 characters including the newline
    # as in b',' or b'\r' or b'\x0A'
    if len(str) == 5:
        return str[2].encode('Latin-1')
    elif len(str) == 6:
        return str[3].encode('Latin-1')
    else:
        return str[4:6].encode('Latin-1')
```

...well, it is functional.

If anyone knows of a more elegant solution perhaps you would be kind enough to post this.

Comment: your code seems incorrect e.g., for `"b'\\r'\n"` your code produces `b'r'` instead of `b'\r'`.

Comment: Thank you, JF. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

`b'\x9a'` is a literal representation of the byte `0x9a` in Python source code. If your file literally contains these seven characters `b'\x9a'` then it is bad because you could have saved it using only one byte. You could convert it to a byte using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast

with open('input') as file:
    a = b"".join(map(ast.literal_eval, file)) # assume 1 byte literal per line
```

Comment: @J.F. I created the file by reading all the bytes at the port into a bytes array. I did some test/checks at this stage to discover and/or confirm the nature of the data. i then wrote out the data in the byte array one byte at a time to a file (which I am now trying to process). The code you provided seems to work just fine, JF. Thank you. Guess I've a lot of reading to do now to work it all out.

Comment: @eryksun J.F.'s code seems to work fine in python3 as you suggested. Thank you too. take care all.

Comment: @eryksun: Indeed, `ast.literal_eval("b'\\x9a'\n")` works on Python 3. I've removed the incorrect remark.